# python read file into 2-dim array for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, text-files

how do you read a text file in 2-dim array, e.g.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fl = open('input.sis','r')

```
lines = [[]]
line=[]
for i in range(1000):
   for j in range(4):
      f= fl.readline()
      line[j].append(f)
      lines[i].append(line[j])

print(lines[0,1])
```

I am trying to read the first 4 lines and assign them indices from 0-3, and repeat that 1000 times.

I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./plot_inputsis.py", line 13, in <module>
    line[j].append(f)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It is important to me to access the array elements by `lines[i,j]`

Comment: can you add small sample input output

Comment: @Tanmy jain Yeah, here is a short excerpt from 'input.sis':
`1.8303759014926360e-15 P000000
     0      0      0      0      0
4.1404266989004412e+01 1.5577688734875311e+01 -4.4524452761790023e-01
-3.5777562203213698e-01 8.4611147063862890e-01 -2.9478803579751186e-02
1.3454764930562923e-15 P000001
     0      0      0      0      0
-3.9537512656691270e+01 -1.6545256213770141e+01 -3.6618807991456764e-01
3.8908856145998982e-01 -8.6648838664890415e-01 7.8041511174565719e-03
1.2834912314620709e-15 P000002
     0      0      0      0      0`

Comment: add mock values( single or  two digits) this looks really clumsy and please also add desired output.

Answer (score -1):

Look into using dictionaries instead of lists.

```
lines = {}
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(4):
    f=fl.readline()
    lines[j] = f
print(lines[0,1])
```